# JavaScript switch case comparison behavior on the case of string

Tags: javascript

I have a switch statement which is passing through two of the cases instead of just the one i would have expected:

```
let name = 'John';

switch (name)
{
    case 'john' : 
        alert('Condition 1 is true.');

    case 'John' : 
        alert('Condition 2 is true');

    case 'JOHN' :
        alert('Condition 3 is true');

}
```

I'm getting the result:

> Condition 2 is true
>
> Condition 3 is true

Why am I getting this result, I don't understand?

Comment: You're missing `break;` statement?

Comment: This is an example of [case fall-through](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#What_happens_if_I_forgot_a_break).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to end each `case` with a `break` statment:

```js
let name = 'John';
    
switch (name)
{
    case 'john' : 
        alert('Condition 1 is true.');
        break;

    case 'John' : 
        alert('Condition 2 is true');
        break;

    case 'JOHN' :
        alert('Condition 3 is true');
        break;
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let name = 'John';

switch (name)
{
    case 'john' : 
        alert('Condition 1 is true.');
        break;

    case 'John' : 
        alert('Condition 2 is true');
        break;

    case 'JOHN' :
        alert('Condition 3 is true');
        break;

}
```

You're missing `break`.